# How to control manage the min and max values in several data pickers?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, razor

In my razor view, I've got a bucle where show by each date a `startdate` and `enddate`. Each datepicker has a range restriction (I mean, `StartDate` cannot be large than `EndDate`).

Here is my razor view

```
<h2>Configure Sixweeks</h2>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) {
<div>
    <span>@Model[i].Position</span>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].StartDate, new { id = "from" + i })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].EndDate, new { id = "to" + i })
</div>
}
```

Here is the big deal, I don't know to specify the min and max value. For example if I select February 2 in STARTDATE, the min value in ENDDATE should be February 2. And that's I haven't accomplished yet.

So I employee the concept from this site: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/ but it's still not working, what am I missing in the following jquery code?

```
$("[id^='from']").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function(selectedDate)
    {
        $(this).next("[id^='to']").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
});

$("[id^='to']").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $(this).prev("[id^='from']").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is the next datepicker the immediate next sibling of the first datepicker, otherwise next will not work. Since you're using a selector to filter next(), I think you might have misunderstood it. It does not find the next element with that ID, it selects only the next element, and selects it if it matches that ID.

Comment: I see, so what other alternatives do I have?

Comment: If it's not the immediate next element, but they are siblings, try `$(this).nextAll("[id^='to']").first().datepicker( ...`, would be easier if you posted the actual HTML ?

Comment: @adeneo thank you, it works so well your solution, please por it as answer to mark as best response

Comment: Sure, I'll add it as answer. Just happy to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not the immediate sibling, but still a sibling, you can use `nextAll()` to find all the next siblings matching the selector, and then `first()` to get the first one, which will be the one closest to the current datepicker, like so:

```
$("[id^='from']").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function(selectedDate)
    {
        $(this).nextAll("[id^='to']")
               .first()
               .datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
```

And there's a `prevAll()` for going the opposite way etc.